# Visual Studio 2010 solution - how copy common exe to two main projects?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, build-process

Situation: An application, that is built into several variations, with different functionality enabled. Each variation has its own main project, with its own output "bin" folder. Call the variations A and B.

There are various common class libraries, which generate dlls. Those all get automatically copied to both output folders. This is working fine.

Now, add another project. It generates an exe, C.exe. It will be loaded as a separate process by the application. (It creates a NamedPipe, providing a ServiceContract via NetNamedPipedBinding.)

When there was only "A" (no "B"), I simply had A and C specify the same output folder.
But now there are TWO places that C needs to go.
For Debug build, must go to A/bin/Debug and B/bin/Debug. Similar for Release build.

The source language is VB, but an answer based on C# projects would almost certainly be adaptable to my situation.

---

I've written an answer by using XCopy in Post Build Events.

Looking for alternative answers.

Is there a way that is easier to maintain / not dependent on manually entering paths?

My concern is that as variants are added, or moved around, it is necessary to know about the Build Events and manually edit them.

Doing work for a company that is not great at keeping track of such details over the years.
Looking for a way that is less likely to break, or easier for a junior programmer to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

In Project "C", Properties, Post Build Events, use xcopy to copy the .exe and corresponding .pdb. Do this for both the "Debug" configuration and the "Release" configuration of Project C.

(For VB, this is under Compile tab, "Build Events..." button at lower right.)

In project A's Properties, find what its output path is. in this case, the path specified was `bin\x86\Debug\`. xcopy needs to be told this path, relative to project A inside the solution; this becomes `$(SolutionDir)\A\bin\x86\Debug\`. The resulting lines, to copy both the exe and its pdb for debugging:

```
xcopy /y "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)*" "$(SolutionDir)\A\bin\x86\Debug\"
```

**This copies ALL files** in "C"s output folder to "A"s output folder.
Before adding this line, examine "C"s output folder. Are there any files in it that should not be copied to A? If so, can they be deleted? (And will they STAY deleted, when you rebuild "C"?)  If not, you will need to specify more carefully the source files, in xcopy line. Or use multiple xcopy lines, to specify the individual files.

Note the "A", which is the main project being copied to.
Repeat that line for "B".
As more variants of main project are created, add a line for them as well.

If one project specifies a different output path, then the lines need to be correspondingly changed.